# CentOS7 のターミナルで、タブによる入力補完に遅延が発生する

Tags: centos

CentOS7のターミナル(GNOME上)でタブによる補完が遅延します。
タブを押して、1～2秒後に補完されることがしばしばあります。
コンソールではそのような現象はありません。
原因をご存知の方は教えて下さい。

Comment: [xrdp でターミナルの補完時に待たされる件](http://sdk0815.blogspot.com/2013/01/xrdp.html) を読みますと、「gnome-terminal の Preferences で "Terminal bell" をオフにする」と書かれています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「音」が原因なんですね。教えていただいた方法で直った気がします。

Answer (score 1):

[xrdp でターミナルの補完時に待たされる件](http://sdk0815.blogspot.com/2013/01/xrdp.html) を読みますと、「gnome-terminal の Preferences で "Terminal bell" をオフにする」と書かれています。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48832/centos7%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e8%a3%9c%e5%ae%8c%e3%81%ae%e9%81%85%e5%bb%b6#comment50759_48832) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*